# Loss of dimensions of dataframe after applying rowMeans() in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I subset a dataframe and i applied rowMeans() on it but the dimensions of the resultant variable ('y') are lost and i am not able to use 'y' in my further code.

```
dim(mtcars)
# [1] 32 11
y = rowMeans((mtcars[,3:6]))
dim(y)
# NULL
```

Why 'y' is no longer a dataframe?. And what can i do to get back its dimensions?.
I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
as.data.frame(y)
# or
data.frame(y)
```

Comment: Why do you think `y` should be a `data.frame`? `rowMeans` outputs one value for each row, so it's perfectly consistent to be just a vector.

Comment: Just attach it to the original df,  i.e. `mtcars$y <- rowMeans(...)`

Comment: If you apply `as.data.frame` function, you'll get a long form data frame (32 rows, 1 column), do you mean you need a wide form data frame (1 row, 32 column)?

Answer (score 0):

When you apply `rowMeans()` you are creating a `vector` out of a `dataframe`. So, you are going from **n** rows and **k** columns to a **nx1** vector.
For a case with `n=8` and `k=5` we would have:

```
> a=as.data.frame(matrix(1:40,8,5))
> a
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  9 17 25 33
2  2 10 18 26 34
3  3 11 19 27 35
4  4 12 20 28 36
5  5 13 21 29 37
6  6 14 22 30 38
7  7 15 23 31 39
8  8 16 24 32 40
> rowMeans(a)
[1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

Comment: Now it's clear to me that rowMeans() output a vector not a dataframe. But now i want to use this vector as a column dataframe in my further code. How can we convert a vector to a dataframe?

Comment: use `data.frame("means" = vector)` for a new dataframe or `my_existing_df$means <- vector` to add means as column.

Comment: @RiteshPorwal both cbo or Sotos' answers can help you out.